# How do I find an ETF that is similar in investment goals to a given Mutual Fund?

Tags: united-states, mutual-funds, etf, expense-ratio

I have some mutual funds that have a high expense ratio.  I am looking to move that money to a low cost ETF but can't find a resource that will map a mutual fund to an ETF.

Once I have that information, I want to do a side by side comparison of specific mutual funds and ETFs to figure out key metrics like expense ratios and performance.

Comment: Your question title is confusing.  Do you mean "find an ETF that is similar to a mutual fund"?

Comment: Have you considered looking at Morningstar's data for your funds so you could consider what indices may make good comparison points to actually have the dots of mutual fund to index to ETF?

Comment: @jbking I have considered morningstar but it does not help me figure out an ETF based on a mutual fund.  That is what I am trying to get to and I may have found an answer

Answer (score 2):

ETF's and index funds (and most mutual funds) track specifically defined benchmark indexes.  The most precise way to compare mutual funds, index funds, and ETF's is to compare with other funds that track the same benchmark.

For example, VEU tracks the FTSE All World Ex US index.  You can directly compare this, then to mutual funds and index funds that track the same index.  For example, among Vanguard funds, VFWAX tracks the same benchmark.  In many cases, only one mutual fund or ETF will track a particular benchmark, but you can find funds that track nearly identical benchmarks.  Going to Fidelity, we see FSGDX, which tracks the MSCI all country ex US index.

To find a fund's benchmark, you can check out its prospectus, which is available from the fund's family (vanguard, fidelity, blackrock, etc) or you can just read its profile some place like finance.yahoo.com.  Search for the fund or etf by ticker, then click "profile" and read under "fund summary."  The benchmark should be listed there.

For a given benchmark, what's the best way to find funds that use that benchmark?  Probably a google search.

Answer (score 0):

With some searching, I was able to find a way which is not the easiest.  I wanted to share this for others that may be struggling with this and if anyone has a better way, please post..

1. Go to ETF database to get a set of ETFs that map to a particular mutual fund. plug in the mutual fund symbol on this website (http://etfdb.com/mutualfund/NBFCX/).  You get a set of ETFs that match the mutual funds investment style
2. Go to Vanguard site to compare your mutual fund and the ETFs from step #1 to compare expense ration vs. historical performance (https://personal.vanguard.com/us/funds/vanguard/compare?navigatingFrom=5)